# How to overwrite the -Xmx50m in JVM options?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, jvm-arguments

I was using a tool. The JVM option is configurable.

Recently, I get a OutOfMemoryError so I add -Xmx1024m in the option configuration as below.

The config.properties:
JVM_OPTION="-Xmx4096m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit"

The cmd log before:
java -Xms16777216 -Xmx50m  com.f.Startmain

The cmd log now:
java -Xms16777216 -Xmx50m  com.f.Startmain -Xmx4096m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit

The tool is still out of memory now as the -Xmx4096m is not overwrite the old one. The tool is not modifiable, and the configuration is only adding new options at the end of the command.

Could someone know a method to overwrite -Xmx50m in JVM options?

Comment: Maybe you just have some memory leak?

Comment: @Maksym The default setting is really small. 50MB. This is a big tool which will load many objects. It depends on what db it connect. Now my DB contains a lot of information which need bigger memory to load it. Thanks all the same.

Comment: look at the start script of the tool and find the place to modify the -Xmx setting. The script seems to append the JVM_OPTION add the end. This results in duplicate -Xmx parameters and the one behind the class name will be ignored.

Comment: @Udo I will do that if I can. The cmd log shows it. The tool is an exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880855/increase-the-java-heap-size-permanently)

apparently for both windows and linux, you can set:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1g"
```

I ran a quick test and this seems to override the commandline params. (unexpected)

my code:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.out.println("mem: " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    System.out.println("total mem: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
  }
}
```

This is the output of running this program

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx20m";
java Test
>> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx20m
>> mem: 19601168
>> total mem: 20447232

java -Xmx123m Test
>> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx20m
>> mem: 19601320
>> total mem: 20447232

# clear java options
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=
java -Xmx123m Test
>> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: 
>> mem: 121773128
>> total mem: 123731968
```

As you can see, the Xmx value on the commandline is ignored until I clear the _JAVA_OPTIONS.